# Docker php:7.3.28-apache-stretch image with openjdk 1.9 running in it

Tags: java, docker

I have a docker container running and I would like to have a JDK 1.9 running in it. I get a openjdk version 1.8 running but I need the 1.9. I haven't success in updating to 1.9. I tried to force it to load the 1.9 but without any sucess.

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0+deb9u1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

```
uname -r
5.10.25-linuxkit
```

Comment: any reason you don't just pick an openjdk image?

Comment: Yes I need php 7.3.28. if I pick an openjdk image I will still need to install php and apache on it to make it work. So it is the same issue at the end. I can sadly not use an openjdk image from my php image.

Comment: The combination of PHP and OpenJDK is unusual and perhaps you are looking more in the direction of a virtual machine than a single-purpose docker container?  Would running two docker images in parallel e.g. with docker-compose be an option?

Comment: Yes it is a single purpose docker container that should run a symfony app. The app needs for some functions to use openjdk. So I cannot really split them into two images since one command launch some php and java code all mixed up. Using a virtual image seems to be a solution but I prefer to use docker in order to have a smooth deployment with a Kubernetes or docker-swarm orchestrer. I already use docker-compose to run multiple image, one of them is a php. Since I can't launch my java code from my php container I end up with the need to have Openjdk and php in the same container.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I guess using a Debian image and adding php and openjdk seems to be a solution.

Comment: Just make what you need. Consider separating this out so you don’t rebuild your base image all the time.